# Shopping Cart application on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: custom

We would like to develop a Shopping Cart application on SharePoint 2010, any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend msdn as a start for ecommerce:

**Introducing SharePoint Commerce Services**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd328362(v=cs.95).aspx

also look into what they already have for you setup and weather its the right thing for you using webparts:

**Commerce Server Web Parts**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh597540(v=cs.95).aspx

as someone on msdn has noted:

> SharePoint doesn't have eCommerce capabilities you will need to
>   develop the Shopping Cart functionality in ASP.NET, use a 3rd party
>   component or use Microsoft Commerce server

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/a53d0525-7286-49ec-a172-adcbbc479a62/

That being said you have thoes choices:

**third party shopping cart at $89**

http://www.coffeecup.com/shopping-cart-designer-pro/

**How to build a no code shopping cart with SharePoint 2010 – Part 1: Background**

http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=165

**Open source commerce:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319962/what-is-the-best-opensource-asp-net-ecommerce-solution

and

http://www.sslmatic.com/blog/16-powerful-and-open-source-e-commerce-applications/

also there is another question asked simmilar to this ;)

[Best Practice for Shopping-Cart like functionality in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34394/best-practice-for-shopping-cart-like-functionality-in-sharepoint)

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**Free Templates/Solutions:**
[Step by Step Shopping Cart - 2 Parts](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=167)
[Best Practice for Shopping-Cart like functionality in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34394/best-practice-for-shopping-cart-like-functionality-in-sharepoint)

**Third Party**
[Shopping Cart for SharePoint 2010.](http://sharepointams.com/modules/sharepoint-ecommerce-module/)
[Creating a simple shopping cart in SharePoint](http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/Comments.aspx?ArticleId=62)
[SharePoint eCommerce](http://www.optimusbt.com/ecommerce_product) 
[SharePoint solutions for
Procurement & Supplier Relationship Management](http://www.corevocommerce.com/sharepoint_ecommerce_solutions)

**Besides all of these, please read the below Question:**
[how to create shopping cart application in sharepoint?](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/72e3490f-05c2-4a8f-b493-b723734d4c79)

I completely agree to that, SharePoint may not be the proper selection for building such solution, you should go for ASP.NET Application instead!