# online product catalog

Tags: list, web-part, publishing-site

I am looking at building a online product catalog with SharePoint 2010.  I have poked around but I cannot seem to find any information, at least with SP2010. Any pointers on where to start?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a kind of e-commerce site in SharePoint? There's quite a few commercial solutions already for this.

Comment: not e-commerce. At least for now. Just a online product catalog for your customers. can you please point out those solutions? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have poked around but I cannot seem to find any information, at
>   least with SP2010. Any pointers on where to start?

The reason you couldn't find Product Catalog for SharePoint 2010 is because it has been introduced for SharePoint 2013 for first time, its not available in SharePoint 2010 so no wonder you couldn't find anything on Internet about it, however if you want to read about it for SharePoint 2013 then you should try this link.

[Product Catalog — You can think of this as almost a published list or library.  Unlike content from SP2010 which was usually entered into pages via page layouts, we are just talking about fields that get filled out — just data pretty much.  Creating this first piece is going to be the subject of this post.](http://johnrossjr.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/sharepoint-2013-wcm-and-search-go-together-like-peanut-butter-and-jelly/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: he said "looking at building a online product catalog with SharePoint 2010" not i cant find it ;) ! he is asking how to make or look for links on info in how to make it! Plus he is asking others who would know about it, its not going to be called cataloge as it would come up with ms about sharepoint stuff. it comes under shopping cart or ecommerce :)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this question and my answer it contains everything that you would want for your catalog :) plus more!

[Shopping Cart application on SharePoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53018/shopping-cart-application-on-sharepoint-2010/53023#53023)

hope it helps!